# ImportError: No module named apps from django-grappelli

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-grappelli

I was working on one django project on my old machine and it was working fine.
Now I am trying to shift my django development environment to new machine (Linux). As a dependency in my project, I am using django-grappelli in it.

I have installed the django-grappelli using following command

> sudo pip install --upgrade django-grappelli

It is installed successfully, but now I am trying to run my application and it is giving me following error.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grappelli/dashboard/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from grappelli.dashboard.dashboards import *   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grappelli/dashboard/dashboards.py", line 13, in <module>
    from grappelli.dashboard import modules   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grappelli/dashboard/modules.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.apps import apps as django_apps ImportError: No module named apps
```

I have search around and tried many suggestions, but didn't work. If I am uninstalling the grappelli, It is goving me error for

> No module named grappelli

Can anyone suggest where am I doing mistake?

Django version is 1.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried different things based on my older setup in which all is working fine.

Downgrading the grappelli to version 2.5.3 worked form me. It was not working with 2.6.1 (latest varsion). Not very sure about if is this the issue with 2.6.1 grappelli version or is there any prerequisite for it.

I have uninstalled the 2.6.1 and installed 2.5.3 grappelli, and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with grapelli, that is being installed correctly. The problem is that django 1.6 does not have the apps folder, or at least your instance of django 1.6 and my instance of django 1.6 (I looked into 1.6.5) both don't have the apps folder.

I'm not sure what you're using the apps namespace for, but that's where the problem is.

Comment: On another pc it is working fine with django 1.6. So, I am not able to figure our the difference between two configurations. Also there is nothing like apps in my installed_apps. It looks like grapelli is using apps and it is not able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

`django-grappelli` 2.6 is not compatible with `Django` 1.6.

The apps folder was created in 1.7 alpha stage in this commit:

https://github.com/django/django/commit/860c2c8bc5c77194c41464655851379bf512a052